# Where savedInstanceState ViewModel stores data in android?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, android-savedstate

As far as I know after configuration changes we can restore state retrieving data from ViewModel and we can retrieve data from savedInstanceState even when system kills the application.

I would like to know where the data is stored when we are using ViewModel and savedInstanceState.

and came across with the code recently which I know is not the best way of storing data  but I would like to know where data is stored in this case I mean where HashMap is keeping data?

````
private static final int CACHE_LIMIT = 10;
private final Map<String, Data> mStorage = new HashMap<>(CACHE_LIMIT);
private final List<String> mKeys = new ArrayList<>(CACHE_LIMIT);```
````

Comment: have you seen the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options_for_preserving_ui_state)?

Comment: @pawel I am not sure if I clearly understand when saying storing on disk and in memory. what each of these stands for?
and storing in Hashmap it stores on disk or in memory?